# IllegalStateException when add a layout into another layout with LayoutInflater

Tags: android, layout, illegalstateexception

I have 3 layouts:

activity_main:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</TableLayout>
```

layout1:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and layout2:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="a"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add layout2 into layout1, after that, add layout1 into activity_main layout. Here my code:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout2, linear, false);
        linear.addView(view);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        row.addView(linear);
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Anh I get a error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call remoteView() on the child's parent first
```

Please help me.
Thanks for reading.

My solution:
Thank all. I think I fixed it. Here my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, table, false);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout2, linear, false);
        linear.addView(view);
        TableLayout row = new TableLayout(this);
        row.addView(linear);
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: which line does it crashes? Is it in `row.addView(linear)`?

Comment: which of the 3 addviews give an error?

Comment: also isn't your linear ==null? because you haven't inflated it and also it is not part of the contentView that is set for this activity

Comment: yes, my problem is my linear == null. You can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'activity_main' layout doesn't have any view with id `R.id.linear_layout`. So the execution of the statement
 `LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout1);`
will result in setting `linear` to `null`

Comment: But I haven't any solution. Can you help me?

Comment: @hungduong Do you want to put 8 instances of layout2 inside layout1's LinearLayout?

Comment: I want to put 8 instances of layout2 into layout1, after that, put layout1 into activity_main layout.

Comment: I think I fixed it. My solution is in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    LinearLayout linear = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout1, table, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout2, linear, false);
        linear.addView(view);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        row.addView(linear);
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```